# Am-Progressiv: What about objects?

Tags: progressive

Do I say:

> Ich bin am Gitarrespielen.

or should I say:

> Ich bin am Spielen der Gitarre.

What about longer infinitives?

> Ich bin am Rasen-vom-Nachbarn-mähen.
> Ich bin am Mähen des Rasens vom Nachbarn.

Which is correct? Am I allowed to form a long infinitive noun when using the am-progressive? Or do I have to restrict myself to using the verb, without any complements, in infinitive, nominalised, and after that use Genitiv? Is both possible? Which is better?

Answer (score 2):

The progressive with "am" is colloquial, it's not part of written language. and there are regional uses.

In Bonn, where I grew up, we would say (but never write):

> Ich bin Gitarre am Spielen.
> Ich bin den Rasen vom Nachbarn am Mähen.

It's quite simple and logical in itself, but it is a strictly regional Rhineland use ("Rheinische Verlaufsform") and probably sounds very strange to everyone outside of Nordrhein-Westfalen. I have moved away and I'm not using this any more either.

Nowadays, I would not use the progressive with "am" in more complex sentences. I would colloquially still say things like

> Ich bin am Gitarrespielen.
> Ich bin am Rasenmähen.

but as soon as more objects are needed, it begins to sound unnatural. I would change to "bin dabei" or "gerade" pretty soon:

> Ich bin dabei, den Rasen vom Nachbarn zu mähen.
> Ich mähe gerade den Rasen vom Nachbarn.

Using the genitive, while grammatically correct, mixes up different registers. The colloquial "am" and the formal genitive case don't go together too well.

> <s>Ich bin am Mähen des Rasens vom Nachbarn.</s>
> <s>Ich bin am Spielen der Gitarre.</s>

I would never use anything like this:

> <s>Ich bin am Rasen-vom-Nachbarn-mähen.</s>

Comment: Sounds good to me even as Austrian. I'd even accept _ich bin dem Nachbarn seinen Rasen am Mähen_.